# Complex stream with multiple findElements and conditions

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `List<RowObject>` for which I need to convert to `WebElements`, then for each row find specific column, then find specific attribute and in the end - `getText()`
How to do it in streams? It doesn't accept what I'm trying to do:

```
List<WebElement> list1 = getsomeRowstList().stream()
                .map(TableRow::getWebElement)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); //it works OK
```

then

```
List<String> list2 = list1.stream()
                .filter(a -> a.findElements(By.cssSelector("locator-for-specific-column-with-parameter"))
                        .stream().filter(m -> m.findElements(By.cssSelector("row-index-locator"))).map(WebElement::getText)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

It does not accept it and underlines the second `findElements` saying:

```
Bad return type in lambda expression: List<WebElement> cannot be converted to boolean
```

I'm quite new to streams

Comment: ' ...find specific column, then find specific attribute and in the end...' are you sure the return type is  `List<WebElements>`? Are you trying to just filter the list of `WebElements` or trying to get a specific attributes list ( `getText()`)?

Comment: please provide the definition of `WebElement`

Comment: @Hülya I'd like to get List (getText) of all Strings from WebElements (where I used findElements)

Comment: then your return type should be `List<String> list2` ?

Comment: yes, but the above code is incorrect, this is my way of doing it but it's incorrect. It's all red-underlined

Comment: Perhaps, you actually mean `flatMap(m -> m.findElements(By.cssSelector("row-index-locator")).stream())`? As the error message says, `filter` expects a function that evaluate to a `boolean`. Apparently, [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) is not the right operation for whatever you want to do.

Comment: The filter takes a Predicate as it's argument.  You should be supplying a function which accepts a WebElement and then returns a Boolean that indicates whether or not you want to keep that WebElement in your stream.

Comment: either I am doing sth wrong or flatMap doesn't work neither. I get 'no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that List<WebElement> conforms to Stream<? extends R>'

Answer (score 0):

`filter()` is an intermediate operation, so `stream().filter();` does not work (see the formatting below).

```
List<WebElements> list2 = list1.stream()
        .filter(
                a -> a.findElements(By.cssSelector("locator-for-specific-column-with-parameter"))
                .stream().filter(m -> m.findElements(By.cssSelector("row-index-locator"))).map(WebElement::getText)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                );
```

Your return type is `List<String> list2`. I recommend you to do the filtering first (gives you the specific `WebElement`), then convert it with `map` (`WebElement::getText`).

I haven't tested but it should be something like this:

```
List<String> list2 = list1.stream()
        .filter(a -> a.findElements(By.cssSelector("locator-for-specific-column-with-parameter")).stream()
                .filter(m -> m.findElements(By.cssSelector("row-index-locator"))))
        .map(WebElement::getText).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: >> m.findElements(By.cssSelector("row-index-locator"))<<  is underlined with message 'Bad return type in lambda expression: List<WebElement> cannot be converted to boolean'

Comment: Can you try: `list1.stream()
          .filter(a -> a.findElements(By.cssSelector("locator-for-specific-column-with-parameter")).stream()
                  .anyMatch(m -> m.findElements(By.cssSelector("row-index-locator"))))
          .map(WebElement::getText).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: the same result :( I don't get why it requires boolean type in this sequence.
It's like I cannot use 'findElement(s) in filter

Comment: It seems `anyMatch()` didn't work, perhaps @Holger 's recommendation may help.